# Confused about accessing properties of a domain object Grails

Tags: grails, junit

In process of learning Grails, I have a couple of domain classes. "User" and "Post". Here is the important snippet from each:

```
//Post
static belongsTo = [user : User]

//User
static hasMany = [ posts : Post ]
```

With these clauses, when a User is deleted, the posts should be as well.

In my integration test, I seem to be accessing these posts incorrectly, and I'm not sure why. Here is the code:

```
//From my integration tests...Not mocked.
def user = new User(userId: 'HenryTheThird', password:'thepassword').save()
...
def foundUser = User.get(user.id)
def postNames = user.posts.collect{ it.content }
assertEquals 2, postNames.size()

foundUser.delete()
assertFalse User.exists(foundUser.id)
assertNull (foundUser.posts.collect{ it.content})
```

The last line gives me an assertion error. I'm guessing this is because when I declare foundUser, it brings in all posts with it. I seemed to have verified this with another test I had written. My question is, how can I assert that the actual foundUser listing in the DB really doesn't have any posts with it anymore? In other words, how can I verify that the posts associated with that user were really deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with timing between hibernate flushing the session and the disconnect between a collection in an object and data in the database.  A better test might be the following:

```
foundUser.delete()
assertFalse User.exists(foundUser.id)
def deletedUserPosts = Post.findAllByUser(foundUser)
assertTrue deletedUserPosts.size() == 0
```

You could also just test the post count

```
assertTrue Post.count() == <some expected value>
foundUser.delete()
assertFalse User.exists(foundUser.id)
assertTrue Post.count() == <some expected value>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when testing for deleting of objects, you're better off clearing the session:

```
this.sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
this.sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()
```

as well as testing the number of objects present:

```
assertEquals 0, User.list().size()
assertEquals 0, Post.list().size()
```

Put these 4 lines after your call to delete() and see if that makes a difference. I think by using your foundUser reference, you are accessing a cached object in the integration test???